# SQL SERVER convert real to decimal

Tags: sql-server

I have an old table where a real column was used. Now we want to transfer the data from old table to a new table where the column is decimal.

When we use "select column from old_table" the values displayed are what we want but after transfer the values are not the same.

How does SQL SERVER determines what to display for the real values.

I have for instance values like

```
|---------------------|------------------|
| displayed value     | converted value  |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 0.2885              | 0.28850001       |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 0.577               | 0.57700002       |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 0.1824634           | 0.18246342       |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 0.116691            | 0.11669103       |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 0.1040202           | 0.10402020       |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 0.1040202           | 0.10402016       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

How can I get the displayed value?

The conversion was done using convert(decimal(38,8), column)

Update

So I am using SSMS to view the results and I need the SSMS algorithm to convert the real value to decimal. Is this algorithm available?

Comment: What is your challenges?

Comment: Remember some numbers that can be represented as an exact number in decimal can not be in binary (just as 1/3 can not be represented exactly in decimal). Your numbers are examples of these. What is the definition for the old_column? Have you tried decimal(38,7)?

Comment: old_column is real like I said in the title. As you saw I am using decimal(38,8). I need it to be 8 instead of 7 because the maximum digits are 8.

Comment: This is tricky. If you really want the values "as displayed", you run into the simple problem that it's up to your *client* to decide how to display them. That the number looks like `0.2885` when you get the table in Management Studio or your client doesn't mean all clients will decide to display it like that, as `0.2885` cannot be exactly represented as a `REAL`, and the *exact* value, as stored, is something like `0.288500010967254638671875` when presented as a decimal number, which, with proper rounding, should indeed be `0.28850001`.

Comment: You can bounce it through string formatting and parsing first (`SELECT PARSE(FORMAT(CONVERT(REAL, 0.2885e), 'G', 'en-US') AS DECIMAL(38, 8) USING 'en-US')`) which may give you what you want for some values of "what you want", but take care that `PARSE` and `FORMAT` (which defer to .NET for formatting) may or may not give you the values as you see them on screen, which (again) are *not* determined by SQL Server but your client software. Use such an approach with caution; calculations involving the value may not yield the same results afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The `real` data type has a variable precision where as `decimal` has a fixed precision (in this case ,8 decimals). So ultimately you have to make a choice on how format the values for the end-user.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't display values. It is the client application (presumably SSMS in this case) that is not displaying the full `displayed_value`.

To wit, below is a query and the results from SSMS:

```
DECLARE @real_values TABLE(displayed_value real);
INSERT INTO @real_values(displayed_value)
VALUES
     (0.2885)
    ,(0.577)
    ,(0.1824634)
    ,(0.116691)
    ,(0.1040202)
    ,(0.1040202);
SELECT displayed_value, CAST(displayed_value AS decimal(38, 8)) AS converted_value
FROM @real_values;
```

Results (text):

```
displayed_value converted_value
--------------- ---------------------------------------
0.2885          0.28850001
0.577           0.57700002
0.1824634       0.18246339
0.116691        0.11669100
0.1040202       0.10402020
0.1040202       0.10402020
```

Running the same query from SQLCMD, the results of the displayed_value are different, showing more precision of the real data type column. As you can see, the converted value is correct based on the actual value of the 'displayed value` column.

```
displayed_value converted_value
--------------- --------------------
     0.28850001            .28850001
     0.57700002            .57700002
     0.18246339            .18246339
       0.116691            .11669100
      0.1040202            .10402020
      0.1040202            .10402020
```

Also note floating point types like `real` are approximate and cannot store all decimal values exactly. This is why the decimal value 0.2885 value became 0.28850001 when stored in the 'display_value' column with data type `real`.

Comment: How can I get the algorithm that SSMS uses to display the real value?